# How to pass collection data through form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing a simple application in .net core mvc.
The problem is with loading related data by view. The 1st time I load the view it gets through wonderfully, I attach data to the view by entity framework include extensions function etc.

This code is on GET, when just displaying the item to be updated, filling fields with current values.

```
public IActionResult Edit(long id)
        {
            ServiceResult<LectureDTO> result = _lectureService.GetById(id, new LectureIncludeOptions(true));
            LectureEditViewModel model = new LectureEditViewModel
            {
                Lecture = new LectureEditDTO(result.Entity)
            };
            if (!result.Success)
            {
                model.HandleResult(result, ModelState);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

2nd time around when submitting a POST, IF the model I've submitted is not valid or the result of the update is not okay, I'd like to just attach errors to the model and send it to the view (by the HandleResult method).

```
public IActionResult Edit(LectureEditViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ServiceResult<LectureDTO> getResult = _lectureService.GetById(model.Lecture.Id, new LectureIncludeOptions(true));
                if (!getResult.Success) 
                {
                    model.HandleResult(getResult, ModelState);
                }
                model.Lecture = new LectureEditDTO(getResult.Entity);
                return View(model);
            }

            ServiceResult<LectureDTO> result = _lectureService.Update(model.Lecture, User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
            if (result.Success)
            {
                model = new LectureEditViewModel()
                {
                    Lecture = new LectureEditDTO(result.Entity)
                };
            }
            model.HandleResult(result, ModelState);
            return View(model);
        }
```

This is how I'm currently loading relationship data on bad editing. I think it's wasteful if I already had it in the model before, just displaying the edit form. Is there a way to pass this data by model?

I've tried this in my form to pass the collection, but everytime I debug this controller action, the value for it is empty.

```
<input asp-for="Lecture.Lecturers" value="@Model.Lecture.Lecturers" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
```

Am I going about this all wrong? Is what I've been doing okay? What could I improve?

Thanks for taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: First, you can't have a single input for an entire collection of data. You'll need to iterate over your collection and enumerate an input for each property on each item. Second, you don't need to do anything special for errors. `ModelState` covers this.

Comment: Okay, so it is basically better to just query the db again for them, rather than adding such a high number of hidden fields?
That is basically what I do in the Handle method, I attach all messages from result to the state as errors if they're of that nature :)

Comment: Yes. Definitely. You should never post anything that you don't want the user to be able to change. Supporting datasets should always be requeried.

Comment: Thanks, was worried I'm doling something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris Pratt pointed out in comment to my thread, you should not post any data to the server, you don't want the user to be able to change. Therefore my case for using collections in this way is invalid. To post collections to the server, write them out in input fields and post them.